# margin-top: 50% works strange

Tags: html, css

I would like to center a div both horizontally, and vertically. I tried to manage it like this:

```
div {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    top: -100px;
    left: -100px;
}
```

The margin-top `xx%` depends on the width of the page for some reason, not the height.
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MxE8Y/embedded/result/

What do I wrong? How to fix it without using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason of vertical % related to parent's width:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

the answer of Hashem Qolami tells you what to do instead :)

Else, you can keep everything in the flow using display: (`display:table`) http://jsfiddle.net/MxE8Y/2/

```
body, html  {
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:table;
}
body {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

div {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

or http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iJgbv/ (display:flex) :

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
}
body {
  display:flex;
}
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:gray;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A percentage value for top/bottom `padding`/`margin` is relative to the width of box's containing block.

> **[8.3 Margin properties: 'margin-top', 'margin-right', 'margin-bottom', 'margin-left', and 'margin'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties)**
>
> `<percentage>` The percentage is calculated with respect to the width
>   of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for
>   'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's
>   width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined
>   in CSS 2.1.

Try using `top` and `left` properties for positioning the absolutely positioned element and use negative values on top/left `margin`:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/MxE8Y/1/)**

```css
div {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A 2016 option using the translate -50% method

**css**

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;  left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/MxE8Y/6/